# rust crate dependencies: norman::Norm trait is not defined for ndarray::Array1

Tags: rust, dependencies, rust-cargo, rust-crates, rust-ndarray

I am trying to get a P-norm for my simple 1D Vec in Rust, but I am failing with every [norman example](https://docs.rs/norman/latest/norman/index.html). Error states that there is `` no method named `norm` found for struct `ArrayBase` in the current scope ``.

What I did:

1. cargo new norman-test
2. cd norman-test
3. cargo add ndarray
4. cargo add norman
5. replace `main.rs` with:

```rust
use ndarray::Array1;

use norman::Norm;
use norman::desc::{Sup, PNorm};

fn main() {

    let a = Array1::from(vec![2.0f32, -4.0, -2.0]);

    assert_eq!(a.norm(Sup::new()), 4.0);
    assert_eq!(a.norm(PNorm::new(2)), (2.0f32*2.0 + 4.0*4.0 + 2.0*2.0).sqrt());
    assert_eq!(a.norm(PNorm::new(1)), 2.0f32 + 4.0 + 2.0);
}
```

I feel like I am missing something obvious, but I cannot find any other examples or some answers on how to properly use crates with dependencies. I'm not even sure what to ask. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of `norman`, `0.0.4`, depends on `ndarray ^0.12.0`, but your `cargo add` will have gotten `ndarray 0.15.16`, which is not a semver-compatible version, so `cargo` compiles the `0.12.*` and `0.15.*` versions separately.

So, `norman` is implementing `Norm` for `ndarray::ArrayBase` version 0.12 but not for `ndarray::ArrayBase` version 0.15.

Things you can do about this situation:

- Change your dependency to `ndarray = "^0.12"` (edit your `Cargo.toml`) so you're using the same version as `norman` is.
- Convince the author of `norman` to publish an updated version.
- Take the source code of `norman` and patch it to work with `ndarray ^0.15`.
- Write code for the norms you want in your own crate, or copy code from `norman` (license permitting).

Comment: Ah, I see what did I miss. When run `cargo add norman` it downloads v0.0.4, which does depend on v0.12. But when I looked for a needed `ndarray` version, I looked at the last version on [norman gitlab](https://gitlab.com/Nuramon27/norman/-/blob/v0.0.7/Cargo.toml?ref_type=tags), and saw a v0.15.4 there.

Comment: You could also use the crate directly from git like that: `norman = { git = "https://gitlab.com/Nuramon27/norman", tag = "v0.0.7" }`.